# How to show real images instead of crosses in SXA experience editor

Tags: sxa

By default in SXA, images of crosses are shown instead of the real images uploaded in the experience editor.

[image: Cross image is showing instead of real image]

I guess this must be the behaviour of the default theme, but why is that so ? And most of all, how to show the real images ? I don't know what stylesheet/script to remove

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find your Theme item and uncehck `Support Wireframe Images` checkbox

[image]

Don't forget to clear your browser cache when switching this option as those images might get cached.